# Change the date and time in wordpress

Tags: date, date-time

Is there a way to change the date and time in WordPress, not the timezone, but the date and time all together, like make it 03-21-85 11:11 PM. I want all dates and times to be changed, not just to one post or page, but to the whole WordPress site it's self.

Comment: Do you want to change the post time of one page/post? Or do you want every single date field to be subtracted with 30 years? Could explain a little bit more detailled what you want to achieve?

Comment: Every single date field to be changed, I just used the date and time 03-21-85 11:11 PM as an example

Comment: When you edit/create an article/page you have the option to edit the post date by yourself. Would that be enough?

Comment: No, I was looking for something that would change the php date function, I was wondering if I could change this through wordpress

Comment: I'm still curious why you want to do this...

Comment: I want to test one of my plugins to make sure it works, http://pastebin.com/ZQisJMPQ, I know I can just switch the months around to see if it works but I was wondering if there was a way to change the php date function through wordpress

Comment: Ah I see. So you want to check if let's say it's 03-21-85 that every content with that date will show up correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'ld like to go to settings > general and then add a custom date format. Like `d.m.1985` instead of `d.m.Y`

Or you write a function that subtracts the time you want from the current date.

Or you set the server time back to 1985. But that's no good idea since it will affect other apps, mysql etc. as well.

Last but not least you could try to set up a second development environment maybe in Virtualbox and then set the OS time manually.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to change the php date function it's self, I starting to think I can't change this through wordpress

Comment: Yeah I think so as well. But you could try to set up a second development environment maybe in virtualbox and then set the OS time manually.

Comment: Great idea! That seems easy enough, thanks! (If you change your answer, I will mark it as "accepted answer")

Comment: @User - Done :D

Answer (score 0):

Edited because perhaps I misunderstood the question. the `date_i18n` filter is probably what you want.

```
add_filter( 'date_i18n', 'wwm_date_i18n' );

function wwm_date_i18n( $d = '' ) {

return '03-21-85 11:11 PM';
}
```

pics or it didn't happen:

[image: pics or it didn't happen]

original answer:

The WordPress `pre_option_$option` filter will do what you want.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_date_format', 'wwm_date_format' );

function wwm_date_format( $d = '' )
{

 return 'm-d-y h:i A';
}
```

any time `the_date()` or `get_the_date()` are called, they will use this format for the date output.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was looking for something that could take the php date function and return a specified date.

Comment: does the date_i18n filter snippet above not accomplish what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that would change every date in WordPress, would it?

Comment: It's not going to change the actual values stored in the database, but all the dates will be displayed as '03-21-85 11:11 PM'. The code posted should not be used without adding some conditional logic or other trickery, as it will likely break database updates if used as is.

Comment: So, in this plugin I made http://pastebin.com/ZQisJMPQ, will the date return as the date specified in the add_filter?

Comment: $date = date('F')

Comment: it's pretty difficult for me to extrapolate what you are trying to accomplish by looking at that code sample. Experiment with the filter...